# CMake project linking Yaml-cpp and Armadillo shared libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, armadillo, yaml-cpp

I'm working on Linux (leap 42.3). I want to write a CMakeList.txt file which creates my shared library containing my code and also yaml-cpp and armadillo libraries in order to use it in another code. So:

- Is it better to first compile and install separately Yaml-cpp and Armadillo from their respective packages and CMakeList.txt files or to build and compile everything together from my CMake project?

At the moment I followed the second way, but I end up with my library which doesn't link well yaml nor armadillo, if I do nm or ldd.

The structure of my project is the following:

In the "upper level" I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(myproject CXX)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "../install" CACHE STRING
"Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories." FORCE)
mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I all my include files ")

include_directories(
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/all my src file directories)
add_subdirectory(src)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(Yaml REQUIRED)
add_library(Yaml INTERFACE IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET Yaml PROPERTY
INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${YAML_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${YAML_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(BlasLapack)

find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)
add_library(Armadillo INTERFACE IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET Armadillo PROPERTY
INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

In the "middle level" I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

function (add_sources target)
get_property(prop_defined GLOBAL PROPERTY ${target}_SRCS DEFINED)
if(NOT prop_defined)
  define_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY ${target}_SRCS
  BRIEF_DOCS "Sources for the ${target} target"
  FULL_DOCS "List of source files for the ${target} target")
endif()

set(SRCS)
foreach(src IN LISTS ARGN)
 if(NOT IS_ABSOLUTE "${src}")
  get_filename_component(src "${src}" ABSOLUTE)
 endif()
 list(APPEND SRCS "${src}")
endforeach()

set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY "${target}_SRCS" "${SRCS}")
endfunction()

add_subdirectory(all my src directories)

get_property(myproject_SRCS GLOBAL PROPERTY myproject_SRCS)
add_library(myproject SHARED ${myproject_SRCS})
install(TARGETS myproject DESTINATION lib)
```

And finally in the "inner level" I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

add_sources(myproject
            mysource.cpp)

install(FILES mysource.hpp DESTINATION include/myproject)
```

So, what's missing? How can I incorporate Yaml-cpp and Armadillo shared libraries in mine? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, CMake find commands like `find_package(Yaml REQUIRED)` sets variables like `YAML_LIBRARIES`. For details, see the source code `FindYAML.cmake`.

To link with the YAML shared library, use this variable:

```
target_link_libraries(myproject ${YAML_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Conan www.conan.io, C++ developers should start using package manager. Then you could define in your conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
armadillo/7.950.1@*****/stable
yaml-cpp/0.5.3@moonforged/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

package for Armadillo is not currently on Conan repository, I have it's own version and not yet published